# User-logging authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, logging, redis

I'm little frustrated because I don't know how well I can refactor this script. I wrote the authentication function but it's too complicated, maybe too large in one function, and seems like spaghetti code. How will I be able to make this a little better?

I'm using Restify framework for NodeJS. There are a function that checks if a user is logged. There is a session hash (`pnp_access_token`) that I need check with another webservice, but I don't need check all times, only the first, so I'm using a cache. I'm using Redis to set a cache and only check the first time.

I don't want refactor business rules.  What can be done about this?

```
"use strict";
var errorResponse = require('../errorResponse'),
    paynopain = require('../../core/paynopain'),
    User = require('../../core/User'),
    cache = require('../../core/cache/cache'),
    validateValues = require('../validateValues'),
    API_PATH = 'v1/';

function authenticate(req, res, next) {

    if (req.url.indexOf(API_PATH) == 0){

        var pnpUserId;
        var validated = validateValues(req, ['pnp_access_token']);
        if(validated.error){
            return next(validated.error);
        }
        var pnpAccessToken = req.params.pnp_access_token;

        cache.read('pnpToken:' + pnpAccessToken)
            .then(function(userId){
                if(userId){
                    storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userId);
                }else{
                    var user = new User(req.logger);
                    return paynopain.getIdFromAccessToken(pnpAccessToken)
                        .then(function(pnpUserIdResult){
                            pnpUserId = pnpUserIdResult;
                            return user.findByPnpID(pnpUserIdResult);
                        })
                        .then(function(userData){

                            if(userData._id){
                                return storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userData._id.toString());
                            }else{
                                var newUser = {
                                    pnpId: pnpUserId,
                                    radius: 1000
                                };
                                return user.create(newUser)
                                    .then(function(userData){
                                        return storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userData._id);
                                    });
                            }

                        });
                }
            })
            .fail(function(e){

                if(e.message === 'invalid_grant'){
                    next(errorResponse.unauthorized());
                }else{
                    req.logger.log('error', 'Error authenticating', {
                        error: {
                            message: e.message,
                            stack: e.stack
                        }
                    });
                    next(errorResponse.internalError());
                }

            });

    }else{
        next();
    }

}

function storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userId){

    var oneHourInSeconds =  60 * 60;
    cache.write('pnpToken:' + req.params.pnp_access_token, userId, {
        expire: oneHourInSeconds
    })
        .then(function(){
            req.userId = userId;
            req.logger.setExtra({
                userId: userId
            });
            next();
        });

}

function init(server){
    server.use(authenticate);
    require('./configuration/routes')(API_PATH, server);
    require('./products/routes')(API_PATH, server);
    require('./tracking/routes')(API_PATH, server);
    require('./lists/routes')(API_PATH, server);
}
module.exports = init;
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question,

I think the first thing to do is read [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/).

You could replace this:

```
if (req.url.indexOf(API_PATH) == 0){
  //Lots of code
}else{
  next();
}
```

To

```
if (req.url.indexOf(API_PATH) != 0){
  next();
  return;
}
//Lots of code,with one less level of indentation
```

This early exit makes the rest of the code look less busy.

Furthermore, in cases like this

```
req.logger.log('error', 'Error authenticating', {
  error: {
    message: e.message,
    stack: e.stack
  }
});
```

You should notice that the object you build has the exact same property names as in the `e` object, you might as well do the the far cleaner

```
req.logger.log('error', 'Error authenticating', { error: e });
```

On a side note, I would also log invalid log-ins, this way you can detect when someone might be trying to hack in to your system.

You can remove some of the arrowness here as well:

```
                    .then(function(pnpUserIdResult){
                        pnpUserId = pnpUserIdResult;
                        return user.findByPnpID(pnpUserIdResult);
                    })
                    .then(function(userData){

                        if(userData._id){
                            return storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userData._id.toString());
                        }else{
                            var newUser = {
                                pnpId: pnpUserId,
                                radius: 1000
                            };
                            return user.create(newUser)
                                .then(function(userData){
                                    return storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userData._id);
                                });
                        }
```

I am not sure why you need 2 `then`'s, so I will just merge them.

```
                    .then(function(pnpUserIdResult){
                        pnpUserId = pnpUserIdResult;
                        var userData = user.findByPnpID(pnpUserIdResult);
                        if(userData._id){
                            return storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userData._id.toString());
                        }
                        return user.create({
                            pnpId: pnpUserId,
                            radius: 1000
                        }).then(function(userData){
                            return storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userData._id);
                        });
```

From a naming perspective;

- I get really annoyed by the `pnp` acronym all over the place, it should be established on top that this for pnp and then you can just go with `user` and `userId` or `user.id`
- `paynopain` <- this is a meaningless name, why would it have `getIdFromAccessToken`?
- `var user = new User(req.logger);`, whatever `user` is here, it does not represent a user since you only use it for `findByPnpID`..
- `radius: 1000`, what does `radius` mean for a user ? What does `1000` mean ?

Finally, for `storeUserIdInRequest` (which lies about what it does), you dont have to wait for the cache to be set, you can simply (and this should be faster) do

```
function storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userId){
  cache.write('pnpToken:' + req.params.pnp_access_token, userId, {
      expire: 60 * 60 //1 hour in seconds
  });
  req.userId = userId;
  req.logger.setExtra({
    userId: userId
  });
  next();
}
```